# How to change the order of values in a dictionary of dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I am trying to change the order of values in a dictionary of dictionaries. Say I have a dictionary of dictionaries that correspond with names, classes, and grades of classes

```
 classGrades={"Computer Science":{"Bob":[98,100,100,88],"Sue":[100,88,100,100],"Jill":[100,100,100,100]},
"English":{"Sue":[100,100,100,100,88],"Mary":[88,90,88,90,88],"John":[100,100,100,100,100],"Joe":[90,90,70,70,80]},"
 Chemistry":{"Bob":[98,100,100,88],"Sue":[88,88,88,88],"Jill":[100,100,100,100]}}
```

The goal is to change the form so that each person's classes have the grade corresponding to it. Expected output:

```
 {"Bob":{"Computer Science":[98,100,100,88],"Chemistry":[98,100,100,88]}, 
  "Sue":{"Computer Science":[100,88,100,100],"Chemistry":[88,88,88,88],"English":[100,100,100,100,88]},
 "Jill":{"Computer Science":[100,100,100,100],"Chemistry":[100,100,100,100]},
 "Mary":{"English":[88,90,88,90,88]},
 "John":{"English":[100,100,100,100,100]},
 "Joe":{"ENG110":[90,90,70,70,80]}}
```

It wouldn't be formatted exactly as shown, it would just be one big list, but I made that so it's apparent how it should be organized. I'm not even sure if I know where to begin on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use only for loops and no methods then you can do this:

```
new_dict = {}
for subject,students in classGrades.items():
    for names, marks in students.items():
        if names in new_dict:
            new_dict[names].update({subject:marks})
        else:
            new_dict[names] = {subject:marks}
print(new_dict)
```

**Output:**

```
{'Bob': {'Computer Science': [98, 100, 100, 88], 'Chemistry': [98, 100, 100, 88]}, 'Sue': {'Computer Science': [100, 88, 100, 100], 'English': [100, 100, 100, 100, 88], 'Chemistry': [88, 88, 88, 88]}, 'Jill': {'Computer Science': [100, 100, 100, 100], 'Chemistry': [100, 100, 100, 100]}, 'Mary': {'English': [88, 90, 88, 90, 88]}, 'John': {'English': [100, 100, 100, 100, 100]}, 'Joe': {'English': [90, 90, 70, 70, 80]}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
classGrades = {
    "Computer Science": {"Bob": [98, 100, 100, 88], "Sue": [100, 88, 100, 100], "Jill": [100, 100, 100, 100]},
    "English": {"Sue": [100, 100, 100, 100, 88], "Mary": [88, 90, 88, 90, 88], "John": [100, 100, 100, 100, 100],
                "Joe": [90, 90, 70, 70, 80]},
    "Chemistry": {"Bob": [98, 100, 100, 88], "Sue": [88, 88, 88, 88], "Jill": [100, 100, 100, 100]}}

result = {}
for _class, names in classGrades.items():
    for name, grade in names.items():
        result.setdefault(name, {})[_class] = grade

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
{'Mary': {'English': [88, 90, 88, 90, 88]}, 'Joe': {'English': [90, 90, 70, 70, 80]}, 'Sue': {'Computer Science': [100, 88, 100, 100], 'English': [100, 100, 100, 100, 88], 'Chemistry': [88, 88, 88, 88]}, 'Jill': {'Computer Science': [100, 100, 100, 100], 'Chemistry': [100, 100, 100, 100]}, 'Bob': {'Computer Science': [98, 100, 100, 88], 'Chemistry': [98, 100, 100, 88]}, 'John': {'English': [100, 100, 100, 100, 100]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). Since `defaultdict` is a subclass of `dict` there's usually no need to convert back to a regular `dict`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

dd = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))

for subject, names in classGrades.items():
    for name, grades in names.items():
        dd[name][subject] = grades
```

Result:

```
print(dd)

defaultdict(<function __main__.<lambda>>,
            {'Bob': defaultdict(list,
                         {'Chemistry': [98, 100, 100, 88],
                          'Computer Science': [98, 100, 100, 88]}),
             'Jill': defaultdict(list,
                         {'Chemistry': [100, 100, 100, 100],
                          'Computer Science': [100, 100, 100, 100]}),
             'Joe': defaultdict(list, {'English': [90, 90, 70, 70, 80]}),
             'John': defaultdict(list, {'English': [100, 100, 100, 100, 100]}),
             'Mary': defaultdict(list, {'English': [88, 90, 88, 90, 88]}),
             'Sue': defaultdict(list,
                         {'Chemistry': [88, 88, 88, 88],
                          'Computer Science': [100, 88, 100, 100],
                          'English': [100, 100, 100, 100, 88]})})
```